# How to use async function inside celery task?

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, celery, celery-task

I've found some similar questions but couldn't find what I want.
I have async function which is I want to use it inside my celery task but cannot call it with await inside task. Is there any way to do it?

**db.py**

```
async def select_users():
    sql = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE "
    sql, parameters = self.format_args(sql, parameters=kwargs)
    return await self.execute(sql, *parameters, fetchrow=True)
```

**tasks.py**

```
from .celery import app
import db

@app.task
def update_credits():
    users = db.select_users()  #here I should call func with 'await'
    print(users)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

1. Define a decorator to apply async to sync. This requires asgiref.

```py
from functools import wraps
from celery import Celery, Task
from typing import Any, Callable, Coroutine, ParamSpec, TypeVar
from asgiref import sync


_P = ParamSpec("_P")
_R = TypeVar("_R")


def async_task(app: Celery, *args: Any, **kwargs: Any):
    def _decorator(func: Callable[_P, Coroutine[Any, Any, _R]]) -> Task:
        sync_call = sync.AsyncToSync(func)

        @app.task(*args, **kwargs)
        @wraps(func)
        def _decorated(*args: _P.args, **kwargs: _P.kwargs) -> _R:
            return sync_call(*args, **kwargs)

        return _decorated

    return _decorator
```

2. Apply the decorator to your async function:

```py
import asyncio
import celery
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger

from ..celery import app
from .async_task import async_task


@async_task(app, bind=True)
async def test_task(self: celery.Task):
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return "world"


@app.task(ignore_result=True)
def say_hello(who: str):
    print(f"Hello {who}")
```

Hope this help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Event Loop method [`run_until_complete`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.loop.run_until_complete):

```py
import asyncio
from .celery import app
import db

@app.task
def update_credits():
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    users = loop.run_until_complete(db.select_users())
    print(users)
```

But if you do not `await` the `db.select_users()` coroutine inside an `async def` your code is not getting any improve by using `asyncio`.

Comment: Getting warning `RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'update_credits' was never awaited
  result = (True, prepare_result(fun(*args, **kwargs)))`

Comment: I guess that error is not related to the question. Did you change `update_credits` to an async def?

Comment: yes I changed to async

Comment: In that case, you have to `await` it in the context you are calling it.

Comment: even if you call await it'll work the first time but there's a good chance you'll face loop errors when the celery task is triggered again